# PyDev.PyUnit.ITestRunListener alternative?

Tags: java, python, eclipse, unit-testing, python-unittest

I have been developing an eclipse plug-in that currently exists as its own icon on the workbench. However, I would like to hook it into the pydev run unit test tool so that the plug-in fires when I begin running unit tests. I have found some information regarding the use of

```
import org.python.pydev.pyunit.ITestRunListener;
```

but eclipse says the import cannot be resolved. I have tried building clean and ensuring that my plug-in dependencies require all pydev related plug-ins. Has the above mentioned import been deprecated? If so does anyone know of an alternative to setting a listener for the unit test run tool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fabioz replied on Reddit and explained that there is no longer an extension point for PyUnit, but you can still access PyUnit information through the API by using the following code.

```
PythonRunner.onPyUnitServerCreated.registerListener(new ICallbackListener<IPyUnitServer>() {

@Override
public Object call(IPyUnitServer obj) {
    obj.registerOnNotifyTest(new IPyUnitServerListener() {

        @Override
        public void notifyTestsCollected(String totalTestsCount) {
        }

        @Override
        public void notifyTest(String status, String location, String test, String capturedOutput, String errorContents,
                String time) {
        }

        @Override
        public void notifyStartTest(String location, String test) {
        }

        @Override
        public void notifyFinished(String totalTimeInSecs) {
        }

        @Override
        public void notifyDispose() {
        }
    });
    return null;
}
```

});